# El uso de "algunas cosas"

Tags: traducción, gramática

> Tu has dejado algunas de tus discos compactos de los Prisoneros en tu coche.

You left some of your Los Prisoneros CDs in your car.

> Yo solía tener muchos Cds de los Doors, pero algunos de ellos he perdido

I used to have a lot of the Doors, but some of them I have misplaced.

How do you say "some of" in Spanish?

Comment: You don't say "some of", you just say some. That's how you get the meaning across. Pero he perdido algunos. Translation: I lost some  of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You left some of your Los Prisoneros CDs in your car.

1- Se te quedaron en el carro algunos discos de Los Prisioneros.

2- Dejaste en el carro algunos discos de Los Prisioneros.

3- En el carro se te quedaron algunos discos de Los Prisioneros

> I used to have a lot of the Doors, but some of them I have misplaced.

Yo solía tener muchos discos de `Doors`, pero he perdido algunos de ellos.

```
Note que por lo menos yo no tiendo a traducir los nombre de los discos
```

Comment: @serfe en este caso `quedó` se utilizaria si fuera en singular no?

Comment: Sí, se podría decir se te quedó en el carro algún disco [...]